# AWS billing overview

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I am hosting two different solutions for two different clients on AWS - everything is hosted out from a single AWS account. Each solution consists of a RDS database and a couple of EC2 instances. I now need to split the bill between the two clients, unfortunately I find it surprisingly difficult to group the cost between the two different applications/clients.

I had halfway expected to find things broken down by "tag" (I have also added the tag `"cost" : $ClientName`) - but the EC2 and RDS usage seems to just be added up in a total. Anyone can recommend a best practice for my seemingly small and simple case?

Comment: Both clients are running on the same AWS account.... ?

Comment: AWS Cost Explorer should let you filter by tag and then group by service - try that?

Comment: Everything is from the same AWS account

Comment: I have tried the AWS Cost Explorer - found that less than intuitive; but I agree it "should" be there ....

Comment: So have you found what you need or not?

Comment: No - I have not yet found what I need ;-) Will investigate the Cost Explorer further.